# Looking for real life examples of World Wide Web sites with great HTML 5 markup usage

Tags: html

I really would like to get into HTML 5 way.
As a title implies, I am looking for web sites that could serve as an example of HTML 5 usage. I am not talking about some kind tutorials. I am also not interested in shiny things like canvas, video, workers, geolocation ect, yes they are important and nice, but I would really like to become from the roots.

What I am looking for are the cases of, not only correct, but beautiful and self descriptive usage of markup (html elements, new and old, [sectioning](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#headings-and-sections) examples, new form features, microformats). So I could `Ctrl + U` them (view the source) and learn from them. As there a lot of not really well written websites, and from the other side, most of them are XHTML served as text/html, I found this a not so easy task. That is the reasoning behind that question.

Will be really grateful for all good links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://html5gallery.com/

Comment: Ah yes, but that's a very large bunch of different random websites. Got any favs?

Comment: I particularly like some in the web app section such as http://html5gallery.com/2010/11/graphr/, http://html5gallery.com/2010/09/trigonometry-calculator/, http://html5gallery.com/2010/08/fyvr/, http://html5gallery.com/2010/07/lislis-painter/, http://html5gallery.com/2010/12/css3-maker/. Also some others including http://html5gallery.com/2010/12/alan-hussey/ and http://html5gallery.com/2011/01/25band-a-del-tamin/ (which you should open in Google Chrome if you can and translate from Persian).

Comment: Thanks, some of those pages are quite good. The problem with many pages from that gallery is that they actually give a bad example. Like wrapping entire site's content into <section> element. Or using just <h1> everywhere, beginning in each sectioning element (I know there is outlining algorithm for that, but most screen readers doesn't implement that, yet - and so, that will be serious accessibility issue).

Comment: @Ernest Shulikovski: That's actually the reason I referenced the parent site rather than the sites individually in my original answer. The fact that each site is independently reviewed and commented on how it could be made better I thought was really good.

Comment: I agree. I missed that reasoning in your original answer :)

Answer (score 2):

check out http://www.html5rocks.com/

Answer (score 1):

My favorite link for some awesome examples of HTML5 usage is at http://www.chromeexperiments.com/